# Rest client step to get oauth token and use it to get data from API in pentaho

Tags: rest, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am new bee to pentaho tool. Can some one give steps to implement the rest call for getting oauth token and use token to get data from API.

thanks in advance for helping in this..

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi onetwo12, I have token name, URL,client id, client secret to get the new token. So i need to know how to pass these client credentials to the url using REST Client step in pentaho.